# $\mathrm dim(W)=dim(W_1)+dim(W_2)+...+dim(W_k)\Rightarrow W=W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ... \oplus W_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathrm W$ be a vector space, is this implication correct?
$$dim(W)=dim(W_1)+dim(W_2)+...+dim(W_k)\Rightarrow W=W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ... \oplus W_k$$

Is it valid for two subspaces only or for a k number of them?

Comment: You forgot the condition that the $W_i$ should pairwise intersect to give $\{0\}$. But this isn't enough with more than two subspaces. For example, Let $W=\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $W_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ be three distinct 1D subspaces in the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: This is true, though: if $W$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with subspaces $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_k$ such that $W=\sum_{i=1}^k\,W_i$ and $\dim(W)=\sum_{i=1}^k\,\dim\left(W_i\right)$, then $W=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k\,W_i$.  This is not true if $W$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Is this true even without the condition that all the possible intersections of the subspaces are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a contradiction if $W_1 = \operatorname{span}\{[1, 0, 0, 0]\}, W_2 = \operatorname{span}\{[0, 1, 0, 0]\}, W = \operatorname{span}\{[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]\}$

The other way is true though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I can't understand the example you made. $\ dim(W_1)=1,dim(W_2)=1,dim(W)=2$ so where is the point?

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso The direct sum $W_1 \oplus W_2 = \operatorname{span}\{[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]\} \neq W$.

Comment: Oh I see sorry and thanks again!